# html5 mobile app where do i store dictionary of 50000 words

Tags: android, html

***HTML5 mobile app creation..***

I am designing a html5 game for mobile requires instant access to around 50000 words. What can i use for this

Comment: If the total size of those words is well below 5MB, you could try localStorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. localStorage if the size required is below 5MB.
2. phonegap to wrap your app in a container (not a web app anymore, but
   a hybrid) so you'll have a database (sqlite) available.
3. app-cache to store all your dictionary in a file and file API for
   accessing that file.